# Ввод с заглавной буквы

Tags: android

Как сделать ввод имени в Person Name с заглавной буквы?

Comment: Надо просто "шифт" нажать.

Comment: @JohnSukhanov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 14):

Добавьте к вашему `EditText` атрибут `android:inputType` со значением `textCapWords`. Другие возможные значения можете посмотреть [здесь](http://goo.gl/KMyuXM).

Comment: да, вы правы, я совсем забыл про inputType

Comment: @JohnSukhanov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 9):

Возможно вам нужно в `EditText`, а именно в `android:InputType` отметить галочкой пункт `textCapSentences`, тогда будет заглавной **первая** буква в **предложении**. При `InputType` равному `textCapWords` будет писаться с заглавной буквы **каждое** написанное **слово**

Answer (score 3):

```
android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
```

Первое - клавиатура набора имени.

Второе - с заглавной буквы.